# Could I set webpack publicPath dynamically? __webpack_public_path__ does not work

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack

I want to setup publicPath dynamically in JS. Our product instances are distributed after webpack build is done. I want to use Font awesome icons so I have tried to configure **webpack_public_path** in my entry JS file, but it does not work. After some investigating I see that **webpack_public_path** is setup, but after my font files paths are set... So my question is, should I have configured webpack module hot loader? Or where should I put my code to set proper publicPath on fly?

Answer (score 0):

the script that sets the variable **must be** the first import of your entry file.

```
// webpack-public-path.js
__webpack_public_path__ = 'https://something.com'
```

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./webpack-public-path.js', './index.js'],
};
```